# Configuring UITableViewCell instances for various models without using conditionals

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to handle many different data types each of which has an associated `UITableViewCell` class and dedicated `configure(for:)` function.

Currently my view controller has something like this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    func failure() {
        fatalError("The row type was unknown, or the row item couldn't be cast as expected, or the specified cell couldn't be dequeued, or the dequeued cell couldn't be cast")
    }
    
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    let item = section.rowItems[indexPath.row]
    
    switch item.moduleType {
    
    case .message:
        guard let message = item as? CardModules.Message,
              let messageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CardCell_Message.identifier) as? CardCell_Message
        else { failure(); break }
        messageCell.configure(for: message)
        return messageCell
        
    case .availability:
        guard let availability = item as? CardModules.Availability,
              let availabilityCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CardCell_Availability.identifier) as? CardCell_Availability
        else { failure(); break }
        availabilityCell.configure(for: availability)
        return availabilityCell


        // etc, for many data types
```

I'd prefer a system where any model can have it's cell class instantiated with a single call in the view controller, and have written the following solution

```
    protocol DataForCell {
        
        associatedtype Cell: CellForData

        func configuredCell(from tableView: UITableView) -> Cell
    }
    extension DataForCell {
        
        func cell(from tableView: UITableView) -> Cell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cell.identifier) as! Cell
            return cell
        }
    }


    protocol CellForData {
        
        associatedtype Data: DataForCell
        
        static var identifier: String { get }
        
        func configure(for data: Data)
    }
```

Which allows the `cellForRowAt` to just call `configuredCell(from: tableView)` on each item, as the array of items is an array of `DataForCell`

The question is, **how can I improve further on this?** It would be great if the `configuredCell` function could be moved into a protocol extension to avoid the need to keeping it as boilerplate in every instance of `DataForCell`

Finally, does this approach violate any important principles?

**Update**
Based on Sweepers suggestion, the improved protocols are this:

```
// MARK: - Data Protocol
protocol DataForCell {
    
    associatedtype Cell: CellForData
}

extension DataForCell where Cell.Data == Self {
    
    func configuredCell(from tableView: UITableView) -> Cell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cell.identifier) as! Cell
        cell.configure(for: self)
        return cell
    }
}


// MARK: - Cell Protocol
protocol CellForData {
    
    associatedtype Data: DataForCell
    
    static var identifier: String { get }
    
    func configure(for data: Data)
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works at all. How are you going to have an array of `DataForCell`?

Comment: @Sweeper an array of protocol-compliant instances is allowed, and the actual data types will conform to `DataForCell`

Comment: How about `extension DataForCell where Cell.Data == Self {` and write `configuredCell` there?

Comment: @Sweeper that's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use different cell type all of them based on a common cell class.

```
class BaseCellType : UITableviewCell {
   func configure(…) {
        print(“Not implemented”)
    }
}

class MessageCell : BaseCellTyoe {
    override func configure(…) {
        … configure the message cell
    }
}
```

Then create a dictionary of cell identifiers in the TableViewDataSource :

```
let cellId  : [ModuleType:String] = [.message : CardModule.message, …]
```

Then in cellForRow , dequeue cell with correct identifier for type BaseCellType and call configure.
In storyboard set the final cell type for each cell.
Note : you may also do this with a protocole.

Comment: I'd rather avoid using an enum as well, which I assume `ModuleType` is?

Comment: ModuleType can be integer or other type